# function to click on specific links

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I need to be able to click l65, only on orders where l63 = sell.

Warning:
This site, for some reason, uses the same ids over and over again per order, but as this is not my site, I can not change that.

code of my current orderlist:

```
<div id="orderlist">
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 08:57:34</label>
<label id="l62">0.00066000</label>
<label id="l63">Buy</label>
<label id="l64">6</label>
<label id="l64">6</label>
<label id="l62">0.00396000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(346046);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:08:35</label>
<label id="l62">0.00078000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">2</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l62">0.00078000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38493);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:12:08</label>
<label id="l62">0.00076000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">14</label>
<label id="l64">14</label>
<label id="l62">0.01064000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38495);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/19/2014 03:13:49</label>
<label id="l62">0.00077000</label>
<label id="l63">Sell</label>
<label id="l64">15</label>
<label id="l64">15</label>
<label id="l62">0.01155000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(38497);">Cancel</label>
<div id="b1"></div> </div>
</div>
```

I would need to be able to click l65, to cancel a sales-order, when the need arises.
I know that the fact that the only thing that changes is the onclick function is very unhandy, but it is what it is, I can not change the site, I'm not affiliated in any way.

If it helps at all, all Sell orders are always at the bottom, so what I was thinking is this:

getElementById always starts looking at the top, right? If there would be a way to start looking at the bottom, it could look from bottom to top for l63 = sell.
If l63 = sell (the bottom one), the sript should perform a click on l65 (the bottom one).

Would this at all be possible?

EDIT:

I just noticed in the above pasted orderlist, that all onclickfunctions for sell orders start with 38, while the buy orders start with 34. Would I be able to do something with that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site uses IDs which are not unique, then there is absolutely no way you're going to be able to reliably use getElementById, since the basic rule of IDs is that they refer to **one element**. Using non-unique IDs is about the biggest no-no in HTML, so with the way your data set is designed, there's almost no unique characteristic you can use to select the specific label you're looking for.

However, since you now know that there is a shared characteristic (part of the order number, as per the question edit) of all the elements which represent cancel buttons for sale orders, here's a way to use the JavaScript querySelectorAll method to grab only the elements you're looking for:

`var sales = document.querySelectorAll('label[onclick^="cancelOrder(38"]');`

Now you'd just want to write a foreach loop to run the onclick function of each selected element. Here's a fully working jsFiddle demonstrating this in a pretty straightforward manner: http://jsfiddle.net/7fEs6/4/

```
var sales = document.querySelectorAll('label[onclick^="cancelOrder(38"]');

[].forEach.call(
  sales, 
  function(el){
    el.onclick();
  }
);
```

Comment: I just noticed in the above pasted orderlist, that all onclickfunctions for sell orders start with 38, while the buy orders start with 34. Would I be able to do something with that information?

Comment: MAAAAAAYBE, but my head hurts when trying to envision how it would work. I guess maybe you could do some sort of selector for all elements that have an `onclick` attribute with a value which begins with `"cancelOrder(38"` and then use `.each` to click each one, but that's making the assumption that you can use jQuery. I don't know offhand what a pure JS equivalent would be.

Comment: But now I'm hooked, so I'm going to play around and try to see.

Comment: Awesome! If you could get that to work, I'd owe you a beer or two!

Comment: Yeah, I got a querySelectorAll which is grabbing all the sale Cancel labels. I'll edit the answer with it.

Comment: I added an answer that might do the trick. hope it helps. Was fun to play around that.

Comment: @Wannes, check the latest edit to my answer -- I've got a fully working jsfiddle showing a very simple way to find and call the onclicks.

Comment: Aha, that works! It displays an alert with the order number (386921). Is there a way to make it now call the function cancelOrder(386921)?

Comment: It is calling cancelOrder() for each item number -- if you look, I defined cancelOrder as a function which calls an alert in there since the cancelOrder function doesn't exist in my jsFiddle. But if you remove that (the very first thing in the Javascript), it should call the version that exists already on your page!

Comment: That works like a charm! New sell orders are now starting with 39, but I can put two of these in a row, one for 38 and one for 39, right?

Comment: Yeah -- it's real kludgy but you could certainly do that. A long-term fix would be to raise hell about the awful use of duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( document.getElementById('l63').innerHTML === 'sell' )
{
dosomething();
}
```

or

```
if( document.getElementById('l63').nodeValue === 'sell' )
{
dosomething();
}
```

for more info visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: That could work, IF I would be able to specify that it should look from bottom to top...

Comment: But as there normally shouldn't be any non-unique ID's, there would've been no need to set a parameter like that.

Comment: try to use classes, same class for all the 'sell', it will give you array of all the divs with nodeValue of sell..then you can add functions to them using indexes..

Comment: document.getElementById will not work since the IDs aren't unique, and OP stated that the site is not theirs and so they can't fix the IDs or add classes. This solves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other comments. That's not a desirable case. But try running this ( IE9+ ):

```
var list = document.getElementById('orderlist').innerHTML;
var orders = list.split(/<div id="b1"><\/div>/);
orders.forEach(function(order, i){
    order = order.trim();
    if (order != '') {
        var sell = order.match(/<label id="l63">(.*)<\/label>/)[1];
        if (sell == 'Sell') {
            var orderNumber = order.match(/cancelOrder\((\d*)\);/)[1];
            console.log('cancelling order: ', orderNumber);
            cancelOrder(orderNumber);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a [working demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hBFyq/3/) ( bring up your console to see the messages )

Here is a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20list%20%3D%20document.getElementById('orderlist').innerHTML%3Bvar%20orders%20%3D%20list.split(%2F%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22b1%22%3E%3C%5C%2Fdiv%3E%2F)%3Borders.forEach(function(order%2C%20i)%7Border%20%3D%20order.trim()%3Bif%20(order%20!%3D%20'')%20%7Bvar%20sell%20%3D%20order.match(%2F%3Clabel%20id%3D%22l63%22%3E(.*)%3C%5C%2Flabel%3E%2F)%5B1%5D%3Bif%20(sell%20%3D%3D%20'Sell')%20%7Bvar%20orderNumber%20%3D%20order.match(%2FcancelOrder%5C((%5Cd*)%5C)%3B%2F)%5B1%5D%3Bconsole.log('cancelling%20order%3A%20'%2C%20orderNumber)%3BcancelOrder(orderNumber)%3B%7D%7D%7D)%7D)()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. However, when I run this code against the site, I get this in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Comment: How do you run the code? Do you paste it to the console? and which browser are you using? the demo is working fine for me http://fiddle.jshell.net/hBFyq/3/

Comment: I run it in Chrome, by pasting it in a bookmark url. Then I just need to click that bookmark to get the code to run.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I used the bookmarklet, and when there are orders on the list, nothing happens, not even a console output. When the orders are manually deleted, I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: Are you sure the structure is exactly the same as the one you pasted. Can you get the HTML from the page you are trying now and update the question?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, and have the pagesource file. Could you provide me with an email address to send it to?

Comment: I contacted you via your site, so you don't have to put your email address here. Thanks again for your time!